# Start post pagination at 0 instead of 1

Tags: posts, pages, pagination, urls

Is it possible to start post pagination count at zero instead of 1?
I want the URLs to be like this:

> ../page (Foreword)
>
> ../page/**1** (Chapter 1)
>
> ../page/2 (Chapter 2)

But by default the URL is not corresponding to my chapter numbers:

> ../page (Foreword)
>
> ../page/**2** (Chapter 1)
>
> ../page/3 (Chapter 2)

Answer (score 0):

The ../page/X structure ties to pagination, not to post names.  I'm sure you could change them but I'm not sure how deep the effects of the change would be.

Have you thought about an alternate solution?

Name each post your chapter name

- Forward
- Chapter 1
- Chapter 2

Add a plugin that adds previous / next navigation functionality each individual post.  Something like [WP Post Navigation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-navigation/).  That way, when someone finishes reading the first chapter, there will be a link to navigate to the next.

You could change your url structure to fit your needs.  For example, if you wanted the structure to look like `http://yoursite.com/forward`, `http://yoursite.com/chapter-1`, etc. you'd just have to change the permalink settings to 'post name' (Admin > Settings > Permalinks).

Comment: Not an option, since I need to have everything in one post. Isn't it possible to let Wordpress count: page, page/1, page/2 instead of: page, page/2, page/3?

Comment: What do yo mean by "Everything in one post"?  If that's the case, the URL structure wouldn't really change. On a side note, have you checked out the [Aesop Story Engine](https://wordpress.org/plugins/aesop-story-engine/) plugin?

Comment: I mean all chapters stored in one post, with <!--nextpage--> dividing the chapters.
Example on my current site: bijbelverklaring.nl/testje/
The only thing I still need is to count URLs from 0 instead of 1.
Thanks for mentioning Aesop, it's a useful plugin but doesn't help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to start post pagination count at `zero` instead of 1 in WP. You can achieve this by customizing the pagination links generated by Wordpress

add code below your functions.php file

```
function custom_pagination_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array(
        'page/0?$' => 'index.php?paged=0',
        'page/(\d+)/?$' => 'index.php?paged=$matches[1]'
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_pagination_rewrite_rules');


function custom_pagination_paged($paged) {
    if (get_query_var('paged') == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $paged;
    }
}
add_filter('get_query_var_paged', 'custom_pagination_paged');
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem too. The only solution I could find is to put the foreword/introduction and chapter one in the first part, then press ALT+SHIFT+P to start the pagination.

This ensured that page 2 has chapter 2.

The problem with this solution is that page 1 is very very long.

If you type in the address `page/0`, you will go to the main page: `page/`

I am sure I have seen sites that start pagination at "0", and "0" even appears in the pagination, but I can't find any source to explain how to do so.